# Use a dictionary to handle variables

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary

i want to know if it is possible to handle variables through a dictionary.

Example:

```
global MyVar
...
MyVar = 0xFFFF
d={"MyVar":MyVar}
def ChangeVar (var_to_change, value)
 d[var_to_change] = value #I know this code assigns a new value to the key...
...
ChangeVar("MyVar",25)
...
```

I want to use the dictionary to "select" which variable I will modify. I can always use an array, but I want to know if it is possible to accomplish this. I do not know very much about pointers in Python.

In C would be something like this (maybe I wrote an extra or missed an '*'):

```
int MyCVar = 0;
int MyCVar2 = 0;
int *MyD[] = {&MyCVar,&MyCVar2};
...
*(MyD[index]) = some_value;
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to explain.

Thank you,

Jonathan

EDIT:
Thank you all for your answers. What I was trying to do was kind of hard since python handles the names and objects quite different. What I did was something like this:

```
class mytype(object):
   def __init__(self,name=""):
      self.__Name = name
      ....
      myDict[name] = self
```

then I can access all the objects using the *Name* of the variable. This is the behavior I tried to explain in the first example. And this is how I would access those objects.

```
myDict["MyVar"].Value = 1
```

Thank you all, your answers gave some good ideas.

Comment: No need to do that... `locals()['Myvar'] = 25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python there is no sugar to get double-pointer semantics. You need to pass a reference some some object around that can mutate the value you want. For example your dictionary could store a function that had access to `MyVar` and could change it.

```
MyVar = 5
def ChangeMyVar(value):
    global MyVar
    MyVar = value
d['MyVar'] = ChangeMyVar

# later..
d['MyVar'](10)
```

You'll be better off designing this to pass around an object that wraps the actual value you care about.

```
class WrappedVar(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

MyVar = WrappedVar(5)
d['MyVar'] = MyVar

# later..
d['MyVar'].value = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think @JBernardo has the right idea.

After staring at your code a while to try & figure out what exactly you were trying to do:

You are trying to create a dictionary of all the variable names, and use that dictionary as a lookup table for changing values?

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals

```
 globals()["MyVar"] = 25
```

Will reassign the global `MyVar` to the integer value `25`

Answer (score 1):

In python all local (and global) variables are already put in a dictionary, so what you can do is access those dictionaries.

You can do it by using locals() and globals() build in funcions.

Ie:

```
locals()['x'] = 'whatever'
```

It is however not recommended:

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local variables used by the interpreter.

from [doc](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/library/functions.html#locals)

A simple case when it fails:

```
def test():
    a = 'a'
    locals()['a'] = 'b'
    print a
test()
```

globals(), otoh is safe to be modified.